When did the floppy disk icon become the standard symbol for the “save” function in user interfaces?
The floppy disk icon is a widely recognized symbol in user interfaces, typically representing the “save” function.

When did the floppy disk icon become the standard symbol for the “save” function in user interfaces?

Now I'm wondering, when did the function of copying in-memory document to disk became known as "save"....

@Therac that dates back to computing center use when one would save a card stack to a tape or disk drive.

@Therac, Suppose you prepare more food than you can eat at a single meal. You don't want to just throw it away, you want to save it for later, right? Suppose you are doing work on a computer, and suppose you don't want to just throw it away when you switch the computer off. What are you going to do with it?

@SolomonSlow I suppose, but Load/Store were more familiar terms to me as a kid.

The Xerox Star (the origin of the 'desktop' metaphor) used a floppy disk icon to represent the floppy disk.  You could save a copy of a document to the floppy by dragging the document icon to the floppy icon.  I don't think there was a distinction between 'close' and 'save' when merely editing documents. That's not something that occurs on desktops before computers.

@Therac - On some systems, the link editor produced executable code in core.  If you wanted to keep it, you'd issue a SAVE command to write the core image to disk. Perfectly clear - if you didn't SAVE it, you would not have it for long.  To recall it into core later, you'd LOAD the saved file.

@Therac, OK, Yeah. You asked, "when...?" IDK, It was before my time, but Dartmouth BASIC had a SAVE command in 1964.

STAD had a disk in its toolbar, but if I remember correctly that wasn't only for saving but also for loading. Would that count?

As someone who teaches computing to 8 year olds, this is a tricky concept for them to understand. "Now press the blue square to save your work!"

@Therac I can say for sure "Save" was used for saving programs as far back as 1975.   Altai 8K Basic, allowed saving and loading BASIC programs to cassette tape.  The commands were CSAVE and CLOAD, But the term Write to save may have pre-dated the term Save, the TECO text editor command to write the document to a file was "W", TECO originated in the 1960's   "w" lives on in VI and VIM with VI as old as Unix.

@dave To most of 1981 users the above icon would totally not have looked like a floppy disk.

@tofro - which just goes to show that saying "the" floppy disk icon does not really reflect history, even (if I recall correctly) in MS Windows.

Floppy disk icons have been around for a very long time, as standard features in GUIs on floppy-disk-equipped systems, as have toolbars or buttons where icons are used to represent actions (see Xerox Viewpoint for example).
However, as far as I’m aware, the first “environment” to standardise the floppy disk icon as a representation of a “save” action was Microsoft Office. Version 4.2, released in 1993 for MacOS, Windows 3.1 and Windows NT, featured icon toolbars with a floppy icon in all programs in the suite.

The use of the floppy disk in this fashion dates back further. For example, Excel 4.0 used it in 1992, Word 2.0 used it in 1991, and Turbo Pascal for Windows and Lotus 1-2-3 had two floppy disk icons, also in 1991. But this wasn’t consistent.

Word 2 for windows (1991?) had the floppy save

Ech, Word 6 (pictured).  A giant leap backwards from Word 5.1a for the Mac.

Interestingly Xerox Viewpoint in 1985 has a toolbar and some recognizable icons, such as blank page for (presumably) new document. It uses text for Save instead of icon, so we can presume that there was no standard icon at that point.

@DanielHatton in 1991 the icon used in Microsoft and Borland programs depicted a 3.5” floppy; the icon used in 1-2-3 depicted a 5.25” floppy.

The 5.25" floppy was a johnny-come-lately device. But I doubt I could tell whether an icon was supposed to be a 5.25" floppy or an 8" floppy.

@KelvinSherlock I had Word for Windows 1.1, it was so early they included a copy of Windows with it to get you started.  I think it had the floppy icon as well, but it's too long ago for me to be sure.

Mini Office Professional on the Amstrad PCW used a floppy icon in 1990 - https://archive.org/details/8000_Plus_Issue_046_1990-07_Future_Publishing_GB/page/n30/mode/1up

It's worth looking at graphical DOS applications too. Those did exist, especially post VGA.

I can't find an image featuring their save icon, but I think the Classic Macintosh (released on 1984) already used a floppy save icon, designed by Susan Kare.

Kare’s breakthrough designs for the Macintosh, which included the smiling computer at startup, trash can for recycling and a computer disk for saving files, are now commonplace in the digital era. They are so recognizable that they are legendary.

https://www.smithsonianmag.com/innovation/how-susan-kare-designed-user-friendly-icons-for-first-macintosh-180973286/
Macintosh was popular enough to consider their UI as creating an standard.

The Macintosh contained a single 400 KB, single-sided 3+1⁄2-inch floppy disk drive, with no option to add any further internal storage, like a hard drive or additional floppy disk drive. (Wikipedia)

and thus, any file save operation involved a floppy, making that analogy very easy to grasp (unlike nowadays, where —despite the meme not being a factual story— knowledge of the icon has clearly outgrown that of the actual floppies). In contrast, the earlier LISA did use a hard disk, with an higher associated cost than the floppy-based Macintosh.
There is a nice story about how the deal with Sony for that 3.5" drive came to be.

No.  I used classic Mac a lot, and Apple did not use icons to represent actions such as Save.  Instead, actions were in menus (File -> Save) and command keys (Command-S).

Classic Mac did use floppy icon, but it was for requesting a floppy, not for saving. It was also used on desktop to represent the floppy.
